# How do I write this mysqli query using joining multiple tables?

Tags: php

I really have a hard time writing queries when I need to join multiple tables into one result set.

I have three tables like this:

store_stock:

```
ID   ItemWeaveType   ItemModel   Cost   Price   
7    3               4           10.00  15.00
```

store_item_weaves:

```
ID   WeaveID
3    MC
```

store_item_models:

```
ID   ModelID
4    HV
```

I am trying to do a query to gather all of the data for item with the stock ID of 7. As a finished result, I would like an array like:

```
Array ( [ID] => 7 [ItemWeaveType] => MC [ItemModel] => HV [Cost] => 10.00 [Price] => 15.00)
```

So, I need to join the data from the tables `store_item_weaves` and `store_item_models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hastily put together query - might work....

```
select * from `store_stock` s
left outer join `store_item_weaves` w on w.`id`=s.`ItemWeaveType`
left outer join `store_item_models` m on m.`id`=s.`ItemModel`
where s.`id`=7;
```

You could then select the desired fields rather than use * for all ~ ie:

```
select s.`id`, s.`price`, m.`ModelID` etc etc
```